# Leaving Website Notification

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery script that alerts the user when they're exiting to a third party website. Works fine when you just click on it, but if the user ctrl+clicks or right click > open new tab the warning message doesn't display. How can I amend this code to have the notification appear regardless of how the user clicks/opens the link?

```
// notification when exiting to third party website
jQuery('a').filter(function() {
    return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
}).click(function(e) {
if(!confirm("You are now leaving...."))
    {
        // return back to page on no.
        e.preventDefault();
    };
});
```

**This is a Credit Union regulation, so I'm not a butthead for doing so.**

Comment: That's a pretty sucky thing to do to your visitors.

Comment: I often do ctrl + click to bypass that warning. Better redirect to a common page and redirect from there (like facebook does)

Comment: Excellent input. Its a regulation requirement for credit unions, so not my choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right click that is context menu is a browser feature. You have to either disable it completely or create your own context menu using HTML.

Here is an answer to address the issue of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click.

If the key is pressed and if it is the ctrl key, just add `e.preventDefault()`

```js
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if(e.which==17)
       e.preventDefault();
});


jQuery('a').filter(function() {
    return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
}).click(function(e) {
if(!confirm("You are now leaving...."))
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.google.com">G</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.